# wcf connection closed notification

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I am setting up a nettcp WCF connection between a client and a server as a reliable session with a 7 day timeout. The client is monitoring a process on the server. Most of the activity is the service raising callbacks to the client. If the service crashes, how can the client detect this and display a "connection failed" message? Do I need to send some kind of keep alive message from the client to the server on a regular basis, or is there some event I can listen to on the client?

My binding code is:

```
     NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
     var reliableSession = binding.ReliableSession;
     reliableSession.Enabled = true;
     reliableSession.Ordered = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try subscribing to the [Closed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.communicationobject.closed.aspx) event of the client or channel. See [CommunicationObject events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.communicationobject_events.aspx).

Comment: But would this event be called because the server went down? How would the client/channel know that the server was dead, as opposed to just gone quiet?

Comment: @Andrew: not sure; I was hoping reliable session would do that, hence "try".

Comment: I have a client / server talking over NetTcpBinding and when the server side is closed down in an orderly manner the client side does not fire the Closing or Closed events.